# IR Drop Improvement with Lower Resistance

Tags: voltage

I’ve recently been overthinking this fundamental concept and it’s been killing my brain.

Maybe someone on here can help clarify.

I’m confused about IR drop. I understand that higher resistance leads to more voltage dropped across a resistive load.

What I’m not understanding is IR drop fixes.

Let’s take a numerical example:

Let’s say I have a 5 V voltage source connected to two different CPU blocks, block A and block B. The wires leading up to Block A have a resistance of 10 ohms and the wires leading up to block B have a resistance of 10 ohms.

The total resistance is 20 ohms so our current is 0.25 A. IR drop leading up to A is 2.5 V and IR drop leading to B is 2.5 V.

Let’s say we lower the net resistances now to address the issue of IR drop, given the lower resistance, we’d now pull more current. Let’s say we lower the resistance of the wires leading to both blocks A and B to 5 Ohms, so our new calculations would be:

Total current: I = V/R -> 5 / 10 = 0.5 A, double the current in the circuit now.

Voltage dropped across wires to A and B is V = I*R -> 0.5 A * 5 = 2.5 V.

In both cases we drop the same voltage, so lowering the resistance didn’t help. Can someone please clarify?

Comment: IR drop normally refers to voltage loss in the wires leading to the loads - not the loads themselves. Draw a diagram showing how you are connecting the loads and the wires feeding the loads.

Answer (score 0):

> The total resistance is 20 ohms so our current is 0.25 A. IR drop across A is 2.5 V and IR drop across B is 2.5 V.

That is true only if the two "blocks" are in series.

> Let’s say we lower the resistance now to address the issue of IR drop, given the lower resistance, we’d now pull less current.

No.

With a constant voltage source (5 V in your case) The current is inversely proportional to the resistance.  As the resistance decreases, the current **increases**.  This is described in a variation of Ohm's Law:

1. E = I x R
2. I = E / R

With a lower resistance, you now pull more current.

If the two equal resistive loads are in series, and they are the only elements in the circuit (assume wiring is 0 ohms), then the voltage across the pair always is 5 V, the midpoint voltage always is 2.5 V.  If the two resistors are not equal in value, then use the total resistance and #2 above to determine the current through both of them, and then use #1 to calc the voltage across each resistor.

Your statement about a lower resistance pulling less current sound like you are confusing voltage with current.  For a constant current through a resistance, as the resistance value decreases the voltage across the resistor also decreases.  When dealing with Ohm's Law situations, always keep track of which elements are constants and which are variables.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, you can see later on that my calculation about double the current coincides with what I actually meant, sorry about that!

Comment: If we have more current now we’re still dropping the same voltage even with less resistance, so my confusion stems from how lowering resistance helps lower the IR drop leading up to the blocks. Thanks!